# Selecting all the formatting Nodes in XHTML

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Using HTML Agility Pack, I am trying to select nodes in XHTML using XPATH.
I want to select the children I listed below in each p tag, but not the grandchildren:

```
<strike></strike>
<em></em>
<u></u>
<strong></strong>
<sub></sub>
<sup></sup>
```

In other words, I'm looking for **A** and **B**, but not the second level of either nodes. Mean while, **A** or **B** nodes can be found anywhere in the set. Note: That **A** or **B** can be any of the ones I listed above.

[image: A and B image to represent the node tree]

If I have the following XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><strike>element 1</strike> and <strike><em>element 2</em></strike></p>
    <p><strike>element 3</strike></p>
    <p><strike>element 4</strike></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I can select the children I listed above in each p tag, it will return the following collection of nodes: strike, strike, strike and strike. Giving me access to the children of each strike.

```
<strike>element 1</strike> and <strike><em>element 2</em></strike>
```

The first  in XPATH means sub `[1]` (I mean instance of strike) and the second, which was ignored is sub `[2]` (I mean instance of strike). This makes sense because that's what my query is doing. Then the XPATH grabs the `<em>` tag and so on...

Another way I can explain this is by saying I want `//a|//b|//c|//d|//e` and **not the children**. Is this possible?

In the end, this leaves me confused in how I can arrive to my solution.

I was looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122.aspx) for answers on XPATH.

Please let me know if you need further research or information. I will provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You use `//`.

This will select all matching nodes across the entire document, no matter at which level. If you want to select certain nodes only when they are directly under a `p`, do `//p/strike`. This will match a `p` node anywhere, but then only `strike` nodes directly under a `p`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly what I was looking for. I believe my examples suggested using `//` and the use of the `p`.

Comment: Why not? Is there any way you can reduce your question to a simpler reproduction of your problem/question?

Comment: Yes, but it will require looking for each type of tag. For example if I went with the `//p/strike`, then would need to look for `//td/p/strike`, `//li/p/strike` etc. I don't want to support more tags, but yes I have considered it if there is no other way. I'm worried about not catching other tags that I might miss.

Comment: If you want to catch all tags, you can just match `//*`. But then the "only one level deep" logic in your original question makes no sense. How about removing all the things you tried from the question and leaving only: the XML, the best XPath you can come up with and the nodes that it mismatches?

Comment: Actually, I think I can work with `//p` because it its a root, I can get the children of each one and go from there. This will target tables as well. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: However, I'm working with CKeditor and I'm worried that if a user manually enters a table, the `<p>` tag wont show up. I wonder if I can force it to have that. The answer is useful, but its not the solution yet. I'm still looking for a better answer.

Comment: I took your suggestion and removed the examples. `//a|//b|//c|//d|//e` and not the children. Is this possible?

Comment: You can probably get `<strike>element 1</strike> and <strike><em>element 2</em></strike>` by selecting `//p/*`, although that would miss the text nodes. Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791108/xpath-expression-to-select-all-xml-child-nodes-except-a-specific-list

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice of *Frank van Puffelen* and a friend at work, I came up with a good solution.

This problem will be solved in 2 steps.

**First**, I will select all the nodes I need `SelectNodes("//strike|//em|//u|//strong|//sub|//sup")`.

**Second**, then I will use a for loop to go through all of the nodes I selected, looking at the nodes parent and if the parent is one of the following: strike, em, u, strong, sub and sup, then remove it and continue.

*Thanks everyone.*