# Using for loop in xslt to traverse over a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml drafted as follows

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      val3
    </node3>
    <node4>
      val4
    </node4>
    <node5>
     val5
    </node5>
    <node6>
      val6
    </node6>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

I m using xslt to loop over `<node2>`
now I want to include values only for `<node4>` and `<node5>` in the results.
What Im doing is

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2[.= node4 or .= node5]/*>
  <newNode>
    value of selected nodes
  </newNode>
</xsl:for-each>
```

have also tried

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2[name() = node4 or name() = node5]/*>
      <newNode>
        value of selected nodes
      </newNode>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2[.name()= node4 or .name()= node5]/*>
      <newNode>
        value of selected nodes
      </newNode>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

but I m getting values of all the 4 nodes i.e node3, node4, node5 and node6

can any one please put me in the right direction?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791108/xpath-expression-to-select-all-xml-child-nodes-except-a-specific-list. Or you can use an if condition inside the For loop to exclude those nodes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I myself got the answer without using templates 
The answer above may also be right 
but the following worked for me like a charm

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2/*[name()= node4 or name()= node5]>
      <newNode>
        value of selected nodes
      </newNode>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your answer suggests that you are trying to avoid using templates at all costs. Anyone with XSLT experience would prefer a solution using templates, and avoid xsl:for-each at all (well, most) costs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all child of `node2` except `node4` and `node5`, you should try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2">
      <newNode>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </newNode>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node4[parent::node2]"/>
  <xsl:template match="node5[parent::node2]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<newNode>val3 val6</newNode>
```